# Passing navigation to BottomNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-native-paper

In my React Native app, I use react-navigation version 5.

How do I pass the navigation object to the scenes in `BottomNavigation`?

Here's the component where I create the `BottomNavigation`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';

// Components
import CodeScanner from '../../../screens/vendors/CodeScannerScreen';
import Home from '../../../screens/home/HomeScreen';
import Vendors from '../vendors/VendorsStack';
   
// Routes
const homeRoute = () => <Home />;
const vendorsRoute = () => <Vendors />;
const scanRoute = () => <CodeScanner />;

const HomeTabs = (props) => {
   
   const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
   
   const [routes] = React.useState([
      { key: 'home', title: 'Home', icon: 'newspaper-variant-multiple' },
      { key: 'vendors', title: 'Vendors', icon: 'storefront' },
      { key: 'codescanner', title: 'Scan', icon: 'qrcode-scan' }
   ]);
   
   const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
      home: homeRoute,
      vendors: vendorsRoute,
      codescanner: scanRoute
   });

   return (
      <BottomNavigation
         navigationState={{ index, routes }}
         onIndexChange={setIndex}
         renderScene={renderScene}
         labeled={false} />
   );
}

export default HomeTabs;
```

In this code, I do have the navigation in the props but haven't been able to figure out a way to pass navigation to the screens. Please also note that the vendor one is actually a stack navigator. In particular, that's where I need access to navigation so that I can open up other screens.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it from `tabBar` prop like below (I use TypeScript) and `BottomTabBarProps`:

```js
export declare type BottomTabBarProps = BottomTabBarOptions & {
    state: TabNavigationState
    descriptors: BottomTabDescriptorMap
    navigation: NavigationHelpers<ParamListBase, BottomTabNavigationEventMap>
}
```

So you pass `BottomTabBarProps` to your custom tab component

```js
<BottomTab.Navigator
    screenOptions={TabBarVisibleOnRootScreenOptions}
    initialRouteName={'Explore'}
    tabBar={(props: BottomTabBarProps) => <HomeTabs {...props} />}
>
    <BottomTab.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreScreen} />
    ...
</BottomTab.Navigator>
```

So inner `HomeTabs` you got `props.navigation`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think your response is for the BottomTabNavigator which is part of React Navigation. I'm actually using BottomNavigation by `react-native-paper`. I understand this is done in collaboration with React Navigation team but documentation is extremely poor and so far I haven't been able to figure out how to pass props/navigation. I'm actually thinking about switching to BottomTabNavigator too. It definitely has better documentation.

Comment: sorry didn't react about paper, well seems like better approach I read the docs as well and are really poor and hard to understand at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may pass data to the vendors screen through the route like so:

```
const HomeTabs = ( props ) => {
  ...
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    ...
    { key: 'vendors', title: 'Vendors', icon: 'storefront', props: props },
    ...
  ]);
  ...
}
```

On your vendor screen you can then retrieve and use the data like this:

```
const VendorsRoute = ({ route }) => {
  const props = route.props;

  <Vendors />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to pass navigation to BottomNavigation. Because in react-navigation v5 navigation can access anywhere with hook
Read this document https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/

Comment: Actually in BottomNavigation you don't get access to useNavigation hook:
"Note that you cannot use the useNavigation hook inside the tabBar since useNavigation is only available inside screens. You get a navigation prop for your tabBar which you can use instead" - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/